# Looping through several datasets for creating a unique one

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to create a macro in SAS that runs some code depending on some settings.
I have three datasets, `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`, all of them saved in the `work` library.
Not all of them need be used: it might be that I want to compare `df1` with `df2`, or just considering df3. My goal is to create a new dataset with specific information from this/these dataset/s. `df1`, `df2` and `df3` have the same variables but different number of observations.

For example:

```
df1
Name Surname Username Score
A.    B.      bad     24
B.    J.      none92  54
 

df2 
Name Surname Username  Score
Jenny    B.      jben42  25
S.       C.      btw     34
H.       H.      hhhg241 64

df3   
Name Surname Username  Score
F.    B.      gd523  22
H.    G.G.    df51  34
```

The macro logic should be:

- take the first dataset;
- take the second dataset (if selected);
- take the third dataset (if selected);
- create a dataset with information from the selected datasets.

I have tried to test the macro as follows:

```
%macro select_datasets(df1, df2, df3, action);

%let dataset1=df1;
%let dataset2=df2;
%let dataset3=df3;

%if &dataset1=y and &dataset2=y and &dataset3=y %then %let dataset_list= &dataset1 &dataset2 &dataset3;
%if &action=1 %then %do; /* create a dataframe that include the observations from all the datasets */
%end;

%mend;

%select_datasets(df1=y, df2=y, df3=y, 1);
```

The above macro does not return any output, though, probably meaning that there are some mistakes in the logic and implementation.
I would need to have a final dataset

```
Name Surname Username Score
A.    B.      bad     24
B.    J.      none92  54
Jenny    B.      jben42  25
S.       C.      btw     34
H.       H.      hhhg241 64
F.    B.      gd523  22
H.    G.G.    df51  34
```

The macro should work even in case there are two or one datasets instead of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not creating a list directly?

```
%macro select_datasets(list, action);
    %if &action=1 %then %do;
            data want;
                set &list.;
            run;
    %end;
%mend;
%select_datasets(list=df1 df3, action=1);
```

That way you don't have to worry about all possible cases.

```
Example:
data df1 df2 df3;
    length name :$8. surname :$8. username :$8. score 8;
    name="A";
    surname="B";
    username="bad";
    score=24;
    output df1;
    name="B";
    surname="C";
    username="good";
    score=25;
    output df2;
    name="C";
    surname="D";
    username="idk";
    score=26;
    output df3;
run;

%select_datasets(list=df1 df3, action=1);

Output:

name surname username score
  A     B      bad      24
  C     D      idk      26
```

Answer (score 1):

I rebuild your code....
Try to use options symbolgen and mlogic to see the results on the log.
I think what you want is a macro variable dataset_list that has the names of data sets you want to join.

```
options symbolgen mlogic;
%macro select_datasets(df1, df2, df3, action);

%let dataset1=df1;
%let dataset2=df2;
%let dataset3=df3;

%if &df1=y and &df2=y and &df3=y %then %let dataset_list= &dataset1 &dataset2 &dataset3;
%if &action=1 %then %do; /* create a dataframe that include the observations from all the datasets */
%put &dataset_list;
%end;

%mend;

%select_datasets(df1=y, df2=y, df3=y, action=1);
```